Prove if $Y$ invertible then $e^{YXY^{-1}}=Ye^{X}Y^{-1}$
One of the properties of matrix exponential is if $Y$ invertible then $e^{XYX^{-1}}=Xe^{Y}X^{-1}$.
It should be obvious but I am so blind that I cannot see why
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{k!}(YXY^{-1})^k=Y\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{k!}X^k\right)Y^{-1}$$
How $Y$ and $Y^{-1}$ are factored out?

$(YXY^{-1})(YXY^{-1}) = YX(YY^{-1})XY^{-1} = YX^2 Y^{-1}$. Do you see how this generalizes?

@Pranay Thanks. This simple observation didn't occur to me.

As noted in the comments,
$$
(YXY^{-1})^2
= (YXY^{-1})(YXY^{-1})
= YX^2 Y^{-1}
$$
This generalizes to $(YXY^{-1})^n = YX^n Y^{-1}$, making the result easy to see.
